# How can I display the user tag and avatar in an embed?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have programmed a bot for Suggestions and Help.
I want to add the authors tag and avatar in the `footer` of an Embed. However I did not found any good sources which help me with my problem.

Here is ***my approach***:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='*')

suggest_channel = None

class hollow(commands.Cog):


    def init(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

@commands.Cog.listener("on_message")
async def deletion(self,message):
  if message.channel.id == (799202156771147796):
    if message.author.id == (811243366795837***):
      return
    else:
      await message.delete()
      embed = discord.Embed(
      title=f'Sugestie',
      description=(message.content),
      color = discord.Color.blue()
      )
      embed.set_footer(
      text=f'id:{message.author.id}')
      embed.timestamp= datetime.datetime.utcnow()
      x = await message.channel.send(embed = embed)
      await x.add_reaction(':white_check_mark:')
      await x.add_reaction(':x:')
  elif message.channel.id == (799202157404356638):
    if message.author.id == (811243366795837***):
      return
    else:
      await message.delete()
      embed = discord.Embed(
      title=f'Help requested by:{message.author}',
      description=(message.content),
      color = discord.Color.blue()
      )
      embed.set_footer(
      text=f'id:{message.author.id}')
      embed.timestamp= datetime.datetime.utcnow()
      await message.channel.send(embed = embed)
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(hollow(bot))
```

Also, for reactions on discord, how can I put this emoji into the code?

```py
✅
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass `ctx.author.avatar_url` to the `icon_url` kwarg in `Embed.set_footer`

```py
embed.set_footer(..., icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
```

Answering your second question, what do you mean by "put this emoji into the code"? Simply copy and paste it

```py
await ctx.send(":white_check_mark:")
```

If you want to add a reaction with it simply get the unicode with `\:emoji:` in discord, send it and copy the message

```py
await message.add_reaction("✅")
```